# How to create AR that shows a web browser over marker using AR js?

Tags: aframe

I have a simple project to create AR that shows a web browser on a marker using AR js.
I have created some experiment using AR js, but still stuck on it.I still haven't succeeded.
Is it possible to create AR showing a web browser window in AR js?
This is the code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/2.0.8/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
        <!-- Marker Definition -->
        <a-marker preset="hiro">
            <!-- Konten yang ingin ditampilkan di atas marker -->
            <!-- Ganti "URL_HALAMAN_WEB" dengan URL halaman web Anda -->
            <a-entity position="0 0 0">
                <a-entity
                    geometry="primitive: plane; width: 2; height: 1.5"
                    material="shader: flat"
                    src="https://website.com"
                    crossOrigin="anonymous"
                    scale="0.7 0.7 0.7"
                ></a-entity>
            </a-entity>
        </a-marker>
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```